# Custom button with curved progress bar in Android

Tags: android, button

I need to design something like this, kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.

Looking for android design

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is stopping you from implementing it?

Comment: `here we can't do spoon feeding !!`

Comment: @Doe I want to create this, but there is no help. I just want to create a rotating button along with upper progress bar to control the volume.

Comment: @Mateen there are so many sample code over internet, don't know why you can't find them. Apart from that I have posted the answer below it is something same as what you are looking for.

Comment: @Doe Thank you. I've done it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a component that implements onTouchEvent. In the onTouchEvent you detect the location and direction of the touch, and you change the rotational position of the graphic, as well as the volume, accordingly. onTouchEvent is documented in the Android API docs under "View".

[Ref link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)

[image]

Write below code into your touch event.

```
switch (event.getAction()) {    
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // reset the touched quadrants
        for (int i = 0; i < quadrantTouched.length; i++) {
            quadrantTouched[i] = false;
        }
        allowRotating = false;
        startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
        rotateDialer((float) (startAngle - currentAngle));
        startAngle = currentAngle;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        allowRotating = true;
        break;
}

// set the touched quadrant to true
quadrantTouched[getQuadrant(event.getX() - (dialerWidth / 2), dialerHeight - event.getY() - (dialerHeight / 2))] = true;
detector.onTouchEvent(event);
return true;
```

And use below link for more reference.

[Custom Button](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/)